# Karaf, cxf and jax-rs - No services have been found

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, apache-karaf

When I install and start the bundle, nothing happens, no output to the console and `bundle:list` reports it as "Active". I've tried using `blueprint-web` feature and I was getting `No resource classes found` exception in logs.

My setup:

- jdk 11
- karaf 4.4.3
- cxf 3.3.5
- `feature:install cxf http`

```xml
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <version>${cxf.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
      <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
      <version>${cxf.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
      <version>${cxf.version}</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm using maven bundle plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
         <instructions>
            <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false;artifactId=*</Embed-Dependency>
            <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.groupId}.${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Name>${pom.name}</Bundle-Name>
            <Bundle-Version>${pom.version}</Bundle-Version>
            <Export-Package>my.base.package.*</Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>javax.ws.rs.*
                            javax.jws.*
                            *
            </Import-Package>
         </instructions>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

`OSGI-INF/blueprint.xml`:

```xml
    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>

    <jaxrs:server id="myService" address="/test">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref component-id="myServiceBean" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="myServiceBean" class="my.base.package.impl.MyServiceImpl"/>
```

MyServiceImpl.java

```java
@Path("/")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
    public AccountStorageServiceImpl() {
        System.out.println("MyService starting...");
    }

    @Path("/hello")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Override
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

I had annotations in the interface at first but moved to the impl class hoping it would help(it didn't).
Is there some additional configuration/feature that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is turns out, project setup is not as hard as it seemed to be.
Only one dependency is required:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And the annotations can be on the interface, should also add annotation `@Resource` for it to get picked up by cxf:

```java
@Resource
@Path("/")
public interface MyService {
    @Path("/hello")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    String hello();
}
```

(annotations should be from `javax.*`)

Complete setup in case someone stumbles upon this question:

1. feature:repo-add cxf
2. feature:install cxf blueprint-web
3. bundle:install {bundle}
4. bundle:start {bundle-number}

Complete maven-bundle plugin config:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.9</version>
   <extensions>true</extensions>
   <configuration>
      <instructions>
         <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false;artifactId=*</Embed-Dependency>
         <Embed-Transitive>false</Embed-Transitive>
         <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.groupId}.${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
         <Bundle-Name>${pom.name}</Bundle-Name>
         <Bundle-Version>${pom.version}</Bundle-Version>
         <Export-Package>my.package.*</Export-Package>
         <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
      </instructions>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```